# Как установить и пользоваться веб-сервером на домашнем ПК под управлением Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon для работы с несколькими сайтами?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, веб-сервер, linux-mint

Недавно понадобилось в личных целях установить на домашний ноут с ОС Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon веб-сервер. Основная цель: установка WordPress, настройка базы данных на PHPMyadmin, и работа в MySQL.

Под "виндой" всё было достаточно просто. Установил целый пакет XAMP или DENWER, а дальше пользуйся парой кнопок start-stop-restart и делай на сайте всё, что надо.

Столкнулся с несколькими проблемами:

1. Как восстановить и поработать на локальном ПК с системой "Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon" простенький сайт. В какую папку копировать файлы, как устанавливать и перезагружать сервер, как установить и работать с базой данных...
2. Какие настройки делать на сервере, с базой данных и на самом сайте(в конфиг.файлах) чтобы всё работало "как надо".
3. Как Решить пару ошибок, которые уже появились после установки PHPMyadmin:
   --  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
   --  Ошибка при указании соединения для controluser в конфигурации.

С последними двумя ошибками уже пару дней по этому сайту пробовал несколько вариантов, но пока не сработало. Буду благодарен всем кто дочитал до конца, понял проблему и дал хотя бы частично ответ на мои вопросы.

Comment: Да так же, как и на любом сервере с linux (VDS/дедике). 1. Куда угодно. 2. Так же, как и на сервере. 3. Использовать правильные данные mysql (обычно пользователь root, пиши в консоль `mysql_secure_installation` и следуй инструкциям – получишь логин и пароль). Сам PMA никаких аккаунтов точно не создает, это лишь веб-приложение для работы с СУБД.

Comment: Все хорошо, а есть более развернутый вариант ответа. Желательно вариант с примером, возможно ссылка на видео пример. Спасибо.

Comment: в основном это делается так - гуглинг - how to install wordpress in linux mint  21.1 и т.д. например,  https://itandlife.ru/os/linux/kak-ustanovit-linux-podrobnejshaja-instrukcija-rukovodstvo-po-ustanovke-linux-mint/ то есть и на русском встречается :)

Comment: @АльбертЧерешко Это буквально гуглится "как настроить веб-сервер на mint". Можно гуглить "как настроить LEMP на debian" – LEMP как раз сборка всего (Linux, Nginx (буковка E = Engine-X), MySQL, PHP), mint менее популярна для инструкций, но по факту debian, mint, ubuntu имеют почти одинаковые инструкции за некоторым исключением, mint так вообще основан на Debian, поэтому можно смело брать инструкции и не запариваться.